# Value Retrieve from Datagridview's Columns

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am working on VB in Visual Studio 2010. And I've seen errors of greatness in which when I double click on a line of datagridview, I get the values of its columns in such a way.

```
Datagridview1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value
```

But the most surprising thing is that with this same code I get the values ​​of different columns each time without changing the index value in Cells(). I also put the name of the column inside the Cells(), but I did not get any value from this too.

```
Datagridview1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("name").Value
```

And the first column of this datagridview Cells(0) always returns the null value itself. I do not know how.
 I have also used some column formating. like

```
With Datagridview1    
    .ColumnCount =2    
    .Columns(0).HeaderText ="Name"
    .Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "pname"
    .Columns(0).Width =100    
    .Column(1).HeaderText = "Son of"
    .Column(1). DataPropertyName = "fname"
```

The big problem here is that it gives value to different columns each time with a single code

Is there any solution available for this?

Comment: Using the line `Datagridview1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value` in the `DataGridviews` `CellDoubleClick` event, I was unable to reproduce what you describe. When you state: _”is that with this same code I get the values of different columns each time without changing the index value in Cells()”_... where is this happening? Is this line of code in the `dataGridViews` `CellDoubleClick` event? Where is this line of code called?

Comment: In addition, from the posted code, the last two lines are missing an `s` on columns, and the column’s `Name` property is not getting set, so, addressing the columns by name will not work until `Column(x).Name` is set. The posted code sets the column’s `HeaderText` and `DataPropertyName`, however the `Name` property is never set for that column. You may want to check out [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes, this code is written in the dataGridViews CellDoubleClick event. But each time this line Datagridview1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value returns the value of the different columns. I get a different value when I load the form again which  contains Datagridview1

Comment: As I commented earlier, I am not able to reproduce this. When I double click on a cell, the correct column values always appear and I cannot get some other column to display if the column value is fixed. You may want to show an example where you get some “other” columns value when referencing a different column.